# Segfault when I run program written in NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I wrote a small program using *NASM* and try to run it, but I got an error "Segmentation fault". I use Linux (Debian) and 64-bit processor.

My program:

```
global _start

section .text

_start: mov eax, 16
    add eax, 24
```

How I assemble and link:

```
nasm -f elf main.asm 
ld -m elf_i386 main.o -o main
./main
```

Result when run:

> Segmentation fault

I also tried assembling and linking this way:

```
nasm main.asm && sudo chmod +x main
./main
```

And get this error:

> bash: ./main: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Why am I getting a segmentation fault? And how can I fix it?

Comment: you don't use `int 0x80` to do an exit system call to exit your program so it eventually crashes after reading beyond the end of your program in memory. Try adding this to bottom `mov eax,1` `xor ebx, ebx` `int 0x80` . _EBX_ is the return value from the program (I just set it to 0 in this example). _EAX_=1 is the syscall number for `sys_exit`. See this 32-bit [syscall table](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html) . The second thing you tried is plain wrong. Assemble/link the original way for 32-bit programs.

Comment: Your program has to include an exit to the operating system.

Comment: @MichaelPetch please move your comment to the answer.